# Wrap text in span after string - using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I want to wrap text in span after the word "Price" using JavaScript/JQuery not php. I tried following but it is not working. I used an expression which I know from PHP.

```js
$('h2#Price').text().replace(/(.*?)Price(.*?)/, '$1 Price <span>$2</span>');
```

```css
span { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Price">T-shirt Price in Canada</h2>
```

I want to wrap "in Canada" in span.

Comment: Remove the `?` and it will work. `/(.*)Price(.*)/`. `?` tries to match as few characters as possible so it will select 0 chars after `Price`

Comment: @Wendelin my code itself is not correct javascript code. please check it again. I don't know much javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use .html to add spans

```js
$('#Price').html(function() {
  return this.innerText.replace(/(.*)Price(.*)/,'$1 Price <span>$2</span>')
});
```

```css
span { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Price">T-shirt Price in Canada</h2>
```

More generic - add a class and each of them will be changed in one go:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.price').html(function() {
    return this.innerText.replace(/(.*)Price(.*)/, '$1 Price <span>$2</span>')
  });
});
```

```css
#PriceCAD span {
  background-color: yellow
}

#PriceMXN span {
  background-color: orange
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 class="price" id="PriceCAD">T-shirt Price in Canada</h2>
CAD 12
<h2 class="price" id="PriceMXN">T-shirt Price in Mexico</h2>
MXN 175
```

Comment: now this is also working. I think this is better. can i accept two answer as solved. thank you dear

Comment: @samar No. You can only accept one. See the update to the second example. And a suggestion: Only my old aunt would call me `dear`

Answer (score 2):

Hi Please check below code for reference

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var string_to_slipt = $('#Price').html();
  //console.log(string_to_slipt);
  var ret = string_to_slipt.split("Price");
  var str1 = ret[0];
  var str2 = ret[1];
  $('#Price').html(str1 + 'Price <span>' + str2 + '</span>');
});
```

```css
span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="Price">T-shirt Price in Canada</h2>
```

Comment: It is also very inelegant

Answer (score 0):

```js
var text = 'Price in 12312412';        
text = text.replace(/(.*Price)(.+)/, '$1 <span>$2</span>');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: And how will this reflect on the actual question? You now need to insert this into the DOM

Comment: Could you clarify how this fits into the question? Could you fix the question's code?

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById('price').innerHTML = 'T-shirt Price in <span>Canada</span>';
```

```css
span { background-color:yellow }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="price">T-shirt Price in Canadaa</h2>
```

Take this, probably some type error have got in your code, now I've fixed that. You told us that you know little js and that is not a problem. If you start out with basics, you will definitely learn it. I just changed the innerHTML(things inside the tags). Hope this helps!